# Plotting spheres around given coordinates in 3D in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, scatter3d

I am working on model of an object sliding on some rough surface consisting of spheres with a small random variance in position. In the graphics I want the spheres to be of a given radius, however when using scatter3 this wont work, the sizes of the circles change when I zoom in or out. I could easily solve this in 2D by using "rectangle"-function instead but for 3D this doesn't work.

Is there a better function for plotting spheres around points?

I have read this https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101738-how-do-i-specify-the-size-of-the-markers-created-by-the-scatter-plot-in-units-proportional-to-the-da. But it either doesn't work for scatter3 or I do it wrong.
[image]

[image]

Sizes change when zooming in.

```
fig = figure(1);
hold on
daspect([1,1,1]);
surface.xnum = 16;
surface.znum = 16;
surface.r = 1;
circlenumber = 0;
for n = 1:surface.xnum 
    for m = 1:surface.znum
        circlenumber = circlenumber + 1;
        surface.circlecentre(circlenumber,:) = [n + 0.1*surface.r*randn , 0, m + 0.1*surface.r*randn ];
        plt.surface = scatter3(surface.circlecentre(circlenumber, 1),surface.circlecentre(circlenumber, 2),surface.circlecentre(circlenumber, 3), 850*surface.r,'filled','r','MarkerEdgeColor','k');
    end
end
```

Relevant part of the code. Setting coordinates to center of the spheres and plotting spheres around them.

Comment: show us also the code you used to plot those spheres

Comment: The full code is 443 rows long. I can either send you it as an m.file or I can give you the numerical values for the red spheres. The red spheres (surface) doesn't change over time, the blue box consists of particles connected by springs that will bounce on the surface given an initial velocity.

Comment: Done now. Note that in plt.surface I multiply surface.r with 850, this is to scale the spheres larger due to the fact that the 'S' property of scatter3 expects 'S' to contain the marker area in points squared and not the radius of the marker. The most important thing is that the spheres are related to the axis so that when I zoom in or out in the figure the spheres relation with the blue object stay the same.

Comment: I see. Now the dots do not change size when zooming, which is what you do not want. While computationally (and graphically) more expensive, have you though of rendering some 3D spheres, instead of d using scatter markers? It will work, not sure how much it will slow your code

Comment: I ment the opposite. The spheres are supposed to represent physical objects. A sphere of radius one with its center at origo will always have its surface at radius one when looking at the units on the axes, no matter how I choose to scale the axes. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Isn't that what I said? I meant that the dots do not change size-on screen. On pixels. They do however, change size on "axis", units. Try the sphere plotting option

Comment: Yeah you are right, sorry, read it wrong. I am trying the sphere function now instead. Is it this one you are suggesting https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sphere.html ?

Comment: Yes. With few edits, you can make them look flat, without lines and single color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution i found by the hint from Ander Biguri. I used surf to plot spheres instead of scatter3.

```
fig = figure(1);
hold on
daspect([1,1,1]); 
colormap summer      
shading interp  % removes the lines in surfplot
surface.xnum = 8;
surface.znum = 8;
surface.r = 0.75;
circlenumber = 0;

for m = 1:surface.xnum     
    for n = 1:surface.znum

        circlenumber = circlenumber + 1;
        surface.circlecentre(circlenumber,:) = [m + 0.1*surface.r*randn ,0 , n + 0.1*surface.r*randn ];  
        [x,y,z] = sphere; surf(x*surface.r+m*2*surface.r+0.1*surface.r*randn, y*surface.r, z*surface.r+n*2*surface.r+0.1*surface.r*randn,'Edgecolor','none');

    end
end
```